# Text font issues with rsvg-convert

Tags: svg, imagemagick-convert, librsvg, rsvg

We were using rsvg-convert for SVG to PDF conversion and it was working like a charm, till we encountered text.

Here's an example-

Command: rsvg-convert -w 842 -f pdf -o testing.pdf testing.svg

Here's the SVG: http://pdf-balancer-693758372.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/development/assets/img/uploads/testing.svg

Here's the PDF: http://pdf-balancer-693758372.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/development/assets/img/uploads/testing.pdf

Problems noticeable in the converted PDF:

1. Underline is lost
2. Some text positioning is incorrect (compare the corresponding character in the bold text right below the last character of the non-bold text in both SVG and PDF)
3. It's is fine in the example in this email but for some fonts, bold
   markup is lost

.

Help!

Comment: Both files are 404ing :-(

Comment: @sayan-bhattacharyya do the testing.svg and testing.pdf files exist any where? where you ever able to find a solution for the rsvg-convert text question?